# NodeJS's Buffer.from(arrayBuffer) creates stale data

Tags: node.js

I'm getting the data from the stream as a Buffer 24 bytes long, which contains different data each time called. In the callback I'm trying to split the buffer into two, and log the two new buffers:

```
// data is an instance of Buffer 24 bytes long
console.log('data: ', data);
const timestamp = Buffer.from(data.buffer, 0, 16);
const eventType = Buffer.from(data.buffer, 16, 8);
console.log('split buffers:', timestamp, eventType);
```

Even though my first console.log shows the correct data, the second one is showing the stale data for the next events, and only after some 12 seconds it updates, and then the next 12 seconds it shows the stale data.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `data.buffer` is already of type `ArrayBuffer` there's no need to use `Buffer.from` - simply use:

```
let timestampBuff = data.buffer.slice(0, 16);
let eventTypeBuff = data.buffer.slice(16, 24);
```

Providing an `ArrayBuffer` to `Buffer.from` creates a shared buffer - that is, reads/writes on the resulting `Buffer` reference the same memory as the underlying `ArrayBuffer` (explained [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_from_arraybuffer_byteoffset_length)). This can create some confusion. Using `slice` creates new memory instead, and should avoid any referencing issue you're having

If this doesn't solve your problem you may need to provide the code which updates the data.

Comment: Two notes. First, I wan't the result to be a Buffer, data.buffer is an ArrayBuffer, so doing slice on it would produce an ArrayBuffer?
Second, I'm OK in the `timestamp` and `eventType` buffers sharing an underlying data with the `data` buffer. These variables get discarded at the end of this snippet, and new callback call will create them again, I don't mutate any of these variables.

Comment: OK. data.slice(start, end), instead of data.buffer.slice is working perfectly.